# Unable to find a specification for 'Pod'

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

My goal is to make the "CleanroomLogger" available as a Pod.
I haven't hosted/made a pod before and this is my first attempt. Pardon me if I ask a obvious question.

I have tried search this forum for potential answers and I haven't found that solves my problem in particular or may be I am something.

## Below are links to the Podspec and the source for the Pod.

Link for the source code is:
https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLogger
Link for the Podspec:
https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLoggerPodspec

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLoggerPodspec.git'

abstract_target 'Eify' do

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'CleanroomLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLogger.git'

    target '<Name>' do

    end

    target '<Name2>' do

    end

    target '<Name3>' do

    end

end
```

### Response on terminal:

pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/ht/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/ht/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/ht/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at 4e310e8335f [Add] YTLiveStreaming 0.2.7
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `CleanroomLogger` from `https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLoggerPodspec.git`

> [!] Unable to find a specification for 'CleanroomLogger'.

---

I tried without the source as well but its the same. I have a hunch I'm missing something very minor, but unable to find what!!

Your time and help is much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great blog for creating Cocoapods. Follow [this guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332). Hope this will help you.

> `pod lib create` will actually help give you a jump start by providing a standard directory structure with a bunch of boilerplate files necessary for a high-quality pod. pod lib create isn't the only way to create your pod, but it is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would be more valuable and helpful for me if you could checkout what I have and give me pointers on any missing links.

Answer (score 0):

The source line should be a spec repo, not a link to your source repo. See the instructions [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods) for setting up a private spec repo.

Alternatively, you can test by pointing the pod directly to a podspec -

```
pod 'CleanroomLogger', :podspec => '/local/path/to/podspec'
```

Comment: Thanks @paul. I tried specifying a pod-spec and I get the following error: `[!] The dependency `CleanroomLogger` specifies `podspec` or `path` in combination with other download strategies. This is not allowed`

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to setup a private repo per say. I'm just trying to make CleanroomLogger available as a cocoapod for anyone interested in using that...

Comment: Also, @Paul - When you say "The source line should be a spec repo, not a link to your source repo" Do you mean s.source in the file at [link](https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLoggerPodspec/blob/master/CleanroomLogger/6.0.2/CleanroomLogger.podspec) should be `s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/vikramhimanshu/CleanroomLoggerPodspec", :branch => "master" }` instead?

Comment: The source line is for pointing at repo's that only store podspec's.  If you read through the docs, you'll get the context to understand the answers you're getting.